# bgcolor attribute

Tags: html, css, colors, background

Havin a table with kind of

```
<tr bgcolor="#aacbdd">
```

And I use reset.css which says

```
...td { background: transparent; ....
```

And this rule removes all backgrounds set in bgcolor attribute.
But I can't just refuse using reset.css
And I can't change HTML (there are tons of plain HTML in the site like this)
Goal is to save these bgcolor backgrounds.
I tried

```
.ololo tr
{
    background: inherit;
}
```

But no use. How do I?

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a few colors, you can use an attribute selector:

```css
[bgcolor="#aacbdd"] {
    background: #aacbdd;
}
[bgcolor="#c73cab"] {
    background: #c73cab;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JN3wW/

---

If you have many many different colors, this can get unwieldy. I'd advise you to rely on JavaScript for that. Here's an example using jQuery:

```
$('tr[bgcolor]').css('background-color', function () {
    return $.attr(this, 'bgcolor');
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JN3wW/4/

Comment: That actually [already happens behind the scenes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#preshint) with `bgcolor` attributes, but may very well have been overridden by something else. I don't think it could have been the `td` rule from the reset stylesheet, unless it also marks `tr` elements as having transparent backgrounds.

Comment: @BoltClock - It seems like the OP's reset also resets the `tr` background: http://jsfiddle.net/JN3wW/1/

Comment: Wow, so I guess that's how tables are laid out in CSS :/

Answer (score 0):

You're using a CSS/Stylesheet reset, and in stylesheets, the latest definition will be used.

So try setting the `style` property of the `tr` rather than the element attribute.

`<tr style="background-color:#aacbdd;">`